# Relation between k-means for k = 2 and OLS regression

Tags: regression, classification, least-squares, k-means

I'm trying to understand the relation between k-means and OLS regression. Specifically, does the line connecting the means for 2-means clustering correspond to the ordinary least square fit on the data, and if not, what would some counterexamples be like?

Comment: What kind of data do you have in mind?  It's unclear what the "ordinary least square fit on the data" might even be because in k-means analysis there are no distinguished explanatory or response variables.

Comment: Seem probable the question mixed up k-means with k-nearest neighbors.